# Approximating π

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I was reading about power series, Taylor's series generated by a function and so on. There, I found a question that said that if P approximates π to n decimal places then $P + \sin(P)$ approximates to 3n decimal places, I proved the statement myself. Now I was naturally fascinated by this beautiful and exact relationship, hence I tried to play a bit with it over on WolframAlpha. At first, all was going well until I put in P=2.9, now this approximates to 0 decimals, hence the addition of sin(2.9) should also approximate till that point. In actuality, this produces an approximation correct to one decimal place. Why does this happen?

Comment: The statement means that the convergence is cubic from some point on (the number of correct decimals approximately is multiplied by $3$). This does not mean that a relatively bad approximation cannot turn into a quite good one. You overinterpreted the statement by applying it for $n=0$.

Comment: An approximation which is good up to 10 decimal places is also good up to 5 decimal places.

Comment: At least $3n$ decimal places.  If $|\pi-x| < 10^{-n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $|\pi-(x+\sin x)| < \frac{1}{3}\cdot 10^{-3n} < 10^{-3n}$.

Comment: +Peter, does that mean there should be  *at least* one decimal place before we can begin to approximate?

Comment: You should probably ask the question of how a sine value close to $\pi$ actually gets computed, especially if you forbid the use of $\pi$. And if the resulting methods, apart from esthetic reasons, are easier as ones to solve $\cos(x)=0$, $\sin(x)=\frac12$, $\tan(x)=1$ which have all fractions of $\pi$ as solution. // With $P=2.9$, you start with an error smaller than $0.25$. The error of $P+\sin P$ is less than $\frac16(0.25)^3=\frac1{384}$, which should be good for 2 digits after the dot.

Comment: The statement about decimal places is an approximate one.  It also does not rule out there being more than $3n$ correct decimals in $P+\sin P$.